# Why does my iPod say "this operation could not be completed" when I try to play any video on my iPod 4th gen?

Tags: video, ipod-touch

My iPod is not playing any videos, not from YouTube or any video playing website. It seems that my video player in my iPod may be messed up. How do I fix that? Can I even fix that?

It's not my internet because the rest of my family can play videos just fine, and it's not YouTube because I checked on other websites, and also on my computer. I already tried refreshing my internet (I have Safari) and I can't do a reset because the iPod's power button is jammed and unusable.